# Read response from CURL.exe program

Tags: c#

My objective is to read the response from the CURL.exe file which returns a JSON string when provided with the necessary arguments.

Ex:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2.0.alpha1/issue/PROJ-1
```

The above code retuns me the following response in JSON format:

```
{
    "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10000/worklog/10000",
    "author": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "emailAddress": "admin@admin.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "16x16": "http://localhost:8080/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10122",
            "48x48": "http://localhost:8080/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122"
        },
        "displayName": "Vamshi Vanga",
        "active": true
    },
    "updateAuthor": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "emailAddress": "admin@admin.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "16x16": "http://localhost:8080/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10122",
            "48x48": "http://localhost:8080/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122"
        },
        "displayName": "Vamshi Vanga",
        "active": true
    },
    "comment": "Read the articles and found some plugins to work with.",
    "created": "2012-03-13T14:45:15.816+0530",
    "updated": "2012-03-13T14:45:15.816+0530",
    "started": "2012-03-13T14:44:00.000+0530",
    "timeSpent": "1h",
    "timeSpentSeconds": 3600,
    "id": "10000"
}
```

I have implemented this code to fetch the details:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("curl.exe -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2.0.alpha1/issue/PROJ-1");        
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("JSON Response" +myString);
myProcess.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

When the above code is run it does not give me any response in the prompt via code. Howver the command runs fine when I manually run in the Command Prompt.

Comment: Why are you using external process for it? .NET already has ability to call the Http resources. Use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

Comment: +1 for [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Comment: `myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();` not `myStreamReader.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 1):

**you could use this sample:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace CuRLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            // Setup the process with the ProcessStartInfo class.
            //
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\curl.exe"; // Specify exe name.
            start.Arguments = "http://curl.haxx.se";
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //
            // Start the process.
            //
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                //
                // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
                //
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you should be using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), here is what could be wrong in your current code...

The constructor being used for ProcessStartInfo is incorrect. You should be getting an exception. Are you swallowing it somehow?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Full\Path\To\curl.exe",
 "-u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2.0.alpha1/issue/PROJ-1");
```

Also you should put a wait time for the command to teminate

```
myProcess.WaitForExit(5000); // Wait at most 5 seconds
```